# nbd-client and nbd-server in docker container: "Couldn't resolve the nbd netlink family"

Tags: docker, nbd

I am trying to build a docker image incorporating this github repo: https://github.com/javgh/sia-nbdserver

This is an nbd-server that caches files locally and then writes them to the sia distributed storage network.
I ran `modprobe nbd` on the host and am now trying to pass through /dev/nbd0 to the container and use nbd-client inside the container to send data the host writes to the device to the nbd-server using a unix domain socket.
I can see /dev/nbd0 inside the container, the nbd-server is up and listening on a socket at /tmp/sia-nbdserver but when I try to run `# nbd-client -b 4096 -t 3600 -u /tmp/sia-nbdserver /dev/nbd0` I get `Error: Couldn't resolve the nbd netlink family, make sure the nbd module is loaded and your nbd driver supports the netlink interface.`

I am running the container with `--cap-add SYS-ADMIN` and `--privileged` so permissions shouldn't be an issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Run the container with something like:

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --cap-add=ALL -v/dev:/dev -v/lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro image-id
```

And see if the module gets loaded inside the container properly.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same, solved with adding `--net=host`

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --cap-add=ALL --net=host -v/dev:/dev -v/lib/modules:/lib/modules:ro image-id
```